# Conditional for development environment in Bigcommerce's Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, development-environment, bigcommerce, cornerstone

Working from the Cornerstone theme in Stencil, I want to be able to do different things depending on whether I am on my local NPM environment or the production site.

Looking at the current URL is not enough as the page has to be already loaded for that. I want to have conditionals in the template, with handlebars, when the markup is being generated. Something like:

```
{{#if developEnvironment '===' 'true'}}
  <p>I'm local</p>
{{else}}
  <p>I'm remote</p>
{{/if}}
```

I see nothing useful in the `theme_settings` vars.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigCommerce provides an actual key/value pair for determining if in development or not within the context.

I'm using stencil CLI v2.1.0, so it might not be the case for older versions.

```
{{#if in_development}}
 In Development
{{else}}
 In Production
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you how did you find out about it? I see no references to in_development in the documentation. Even a google search throws no pertinent results

Comment: You can find a reference of the all the stencil context objects here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/global-objects-and-properties/models/context

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this conditional statement:

```
{{#if settings.maintenance.secure_path '==' 'http://localhost:undefined'}}
  You are running on development.
{{else}}
  You are running on production.
{{/if}}
```

Comment: This is the solution! Just in some cases the local path is defined (http://localhost:8181), I don't know how it varies. I think you should include the {{has}} helper with localhost and that'll do the trick for all cases

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own custom `theme_settings` values.

First, navigate to the `./config.json` file. Look for the `variations` array in this file.
It should look something like this:

```
  "variations": [
    {
      "name": "Light",
      "id": "light",
      "meta": {...},
      "images": {...},
      "settings": {
          "developEnvironment": true,
...
```

Under the settings object you can add your own custom `theme_settings` values just like I did above: `"developEnvironment": true,`. Now in your theme file you can do something like this:

```
    {{#if theme_settings.developEnvironment}}
        <!-- Do something -->
    {{/if}}
```

Comment: I use that a lot, but the problem is I would need to change the setting every time before uploading and change it back for development. The idea is to have an automatic way for it to work

Comment: You would need to have two different "styles"/"themes" - change "Light" to "Development" and "Bold" to "Production". Remove all of the different settings that affect styling, so the only settings you'll have are the different things you want between dev/prod. Only apply the production version to your site, and develop inside of the "Development" style locally. You could try using dotenv-webpack into your webpack build and use a prod/dev set of environment variables, but that will only be useful for you JS, not handlebars.

Comment: "Remove all of the different settings that affect styling" sounds awful, but I do appreciate the input

Comment: I don’t think you understand what I am suggesting at all. You have a top level settings object in config.json. This contains metadata which is referenced as “theme_settings” in handlebars templates. You also have “Variations” - “Light”, “Bold”, and “Warm” - these are super-sets of those values that will over-write the top level settings when you apply that “style” in your bigcommerce store. You can launch that specific style locally by doing “stencil start -v Light”, etc. The point is to set a top level style, and remove the variance between light and bold

Comment: Most people don’t use all 3 styles at all - this is more for theme vendors to give variations to their theme when they market it. Most BC users just apply the first “style” in that list automatically. What I’m suggesting is that you re-name your first variation to “Development”, and second to “Production” , and add an entry in config.json such as “development_version”: true to the dev style. Have your handlebars {{#if theme_settings.development_version}} dev stuff {{else}} prod stuff {{/if}} . Always run the dev style locally and always apply the prod style in deployment.

Comment: It still implies having different versions of the theme between dev and production, which opens the doors to big problems. Your answer with the conditional statement, though, is what I was looking for